# Making a small private iphone webapp. Lightest possible datastore?

Tags: database

Making a new version of my calorie counter. I will use it daily to track a shopping list, daily foods, daily macros. Just a lot of number crunching and displaying.

What would the lightest option be in terms of a data store?

Comment: Do you wanna save your data on server or client side ?

Comment: Whichever is fastest. I want to press a button and I want the data to be there immediately. No load times. I don't know enough JavaScript to manipulate the DOM effectively and store resulting values post-computation, so none of that. Actually, can't I do it clientside with JS working with CSV?

Comment: JS cannot access files (afaik), JS can only handle stuff "within" the browser. If clientside data storage is okay for you, then i would recommend HTML5 localStorage (see my answer below)!

Comment: Wonderful, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with

1. Serverside: SQLite (one-file-database, can handle queries like a real database)
2. Clientside: HTML5 localStorage, that's something like "more powerful cookies" directly in the browser. More here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
3. Serverside: Writing a simple text-file. Boom!